Using Adafruit PiTFT 2.4" and I2S Amplifier MAX98357A at the same time
I built my own "Gameboy" with a Rapberry Zero, the Adafruit Display (https://www.adafruit.com/product/2455) and Adafruit Soundamplifier (https://www.adafruit.com/product/3006) running RetroPie.
So far everything works BUT not sound and the GPIOs at the same time.
I mixed a bunch of tutorials:
https://beardedmaker.com/wiki/index.php?title=Game_Boy_Zero#Display
https://learn.adafruit.com/pigrrl-raspberry-pi-gameboy
https://learn.adafruit.com/pigrrl-zero
and I got the PiTFT to work and also all the buttons I need soldered to the display or Pi Zero directly. All of them work.
For sound I use the Adafruit MAX98357A like in the first tutorial and added "dtoverlay=max98357a" to my pi config file. So sound also works, but all the buttons stop working when adding this line... But the Display itself still works, so maybe there is a workaround to get everything to work?
Can anyone help me out here? I found this thread (How to enable SPI1 and SPI0 at the same time?) talking about the issue, but this is bit to advanced for me (I'm fairly new to this and quite happy I even got to this point).
Here my full config:
disable_overscan=1
dtoverlay=max98357a
gpu_mem=44
disable_audio_dither=1
gpu_mem_256=128
gpu_mem_512=256
gpu_mem_1024=256
overscan_scale=1
dtoverlay=pitft22,rotate=270,speed=60000000,fps=40
display_rotate=0
hdmi_cvt=320 240 60 1 0 0 0
arm_freq=1000
core_freq=500
sdram_freq=450
over_voltage=6
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt

And all the soldered connections:
26-Pin Connector on Display:
GPIO2     - Left Button
GPIO3     - Right Button
GPIO4     - Down Button
GPIO17    - Up Button
GPIO27    - A Button
GPIO22    - Y Button
GPIO23    - B Button
GPIO18    - Soundamplifier BCLK

Button Holes on Display:
GPIO5     - L Button
GPIO6     - SELECT Button
GPIO12    - START Button
GPIO13    - R Button
GPIO16    - X Button

Directly soldered to Pi Pins:
GPIO19    - Soundamplifier LRC
GPIO21    - Soundamplifier DIN
GPIO26    - HOTKEY Button

Thanks to everyone even reading this :)
I will happily provide any extra info you need.
Small extra problem: when i touch the display a bit too hard the Pi reboots. Any way to fix this?

then update what it says

What OS is installed (detail including version)?

RetroPie 4.8 for Pi Zero, latest version installed via Raspberry Pi Imager
